# System of equations with 4 variables

Tags: systems-of-equations

Thanks by your help I found a solution and I will leave it here if someone finds this problem interesting

$$\begin{cases}ab+1&=&(c+1)(d+1)\\
cd+1&=&(a-1)(b-1)\end{cases}$$

When you expand the both sides of the equations you get:
$$\begin{cases}ab+1&=&cd+c+d+1\\
cd+1&=&ab-a-b+1\end{cases}$$

Sum both equations and you get:
$$\begin{cases}a+b&=&c+d\\
ab-cd&=&a+b\end{cases}$$

From here it’s obvious that

ab-cd=a+b=c+d and let’s consider these sums equal to *s*

Then

s=a(s-a)-c(s-c)=(a-c)(s-a-c)

If *s* is odd then *a-c* & *s-a-c* are also odd but then their sum *s-2c* would be even and so *s* would be even too

Therefore *a-c* and *s-a-c* are even & let’s consider a-c=2x and s-a-c=2y where x,y are integers

From this we get that s=4xy and then we’re done

We get (a,b,c,d)=(2xy+x-y,2xy-x+y,2xy-x-y,2xy+x+y)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: When you expand it and sum both equations you get a+b=c+d and then idk what to do. One obvious solution is 0;0;0;0

Comment: The comments section is not the place to add your work.

Comment: oh okay. I don’t really know how to work with this app but I’ll try

Comment: The system has infinitely many solutions. To find them, think $b$ and $c$ as given constants and solve for $a$ and $d$. You'll end with a parametrization of all the solutions.

Comment: I can only find c=(a+b)/2      How do you suggest I find the other parameters

Comment: If you think $b$ and $c$ as constants you have a system of two **linear** equations ($a+b = c+d$  and $cd=ab-a-b$) in two unknowns ($a$ and $d$). Do you know how to solve a system of two linear equations in two unknowns?

Comment: Yeah I found a solution. Should I delete my post after I got what I needed? Thanks for the help all of you guys are amazing